Pendo and SendGrid + marketing e-mails - does one overlap the other somehow?
I'm looking into the usage of one of these products for marketing communications through e-mail, to customers. This is a topic I'm not so comfortable with, so the questions may not be perfect but I'll try.
I know that SendGrid is great for transactional e-mails, but for marketing ones does Pendo fit? Or should I still use SendGrid + inject any sort of scripts in order to provide analytics to Pendo?
Or is it pendo suitable for generating scripts for tracking and those should be embebed on Sendgrid templates for user tracking?
